# Declaring variadic templates of pointer to member functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, g++, variadic-templates

I want to build my own unit test library where I would like to setup test cases as follows:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::string concatenate(Args&&... args);

class my_test : public unit_test::test {
public:
    my_test(int i, float f, double d) : i_(i), f_(f), d_(d) { }
    void test1() { assert_true(i_ % 5 == 0, concatenate("i(", i_, ") not divisible by 5")); }
    void test2() { assert_true(i_ > 0, concatenate("i(", i_, ") not greater than 0")); }
    void test3() { assert_true(i_ % 2 == 0, concatenate("i(", i_, ") not divisible by 2")); }
private:
    int i_;
    float f_;
    double d_;
};

int main()
{
    unit_test::test_case<my_test,
        &my_test::test1
        &my_test::test2
        &my_test::test3> my_test_case;
    result r = my_test_case(1, 1.0f, 1.0);
}
```

To be able to define the test_case template class, I need to be able to declare variadic templates of pointers to member functions:

```
class result {
    unsigned int num_failures_;
    unsigned int num_tests_;
};

template <typename Test, void(Test::*...MemFns)()>
class test_case;
```

Unfortunately, g++-4.8 and above gives the following error:

```
main.cpp:137:52: error: template argument 3 is invalid
 class test_case <Test, &Test::First, &Test::...Rest> {
                                                    ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:194:28: error: template argument 2 is invalid
             &my_test::test3>()(1, 1.0f, 1.0);
```

And surprisingly, g++-4.7 compiles and runs some invalid code!

What is the correct way of declaring variadic templates of pointer to member functions?

[Here is the full code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3d313b218208bdc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
template <typename Test, void(Test::*First)(), void(Test::*...Rest)()>
class test_case <Test, &Test::First, &Test::...Rest>
```

into:

```
template <typename Test, void(Test::*First)(), void(Test::*...Rest)()>
class test_case <Test, First, Rest...>
```

As well as:

```
test_case<Test, &Test::...Rest>()(args...);
```

into:

```
test_case<Test, Rest...>()(args...);
```

Comment: Piotr, why does g++-4.7 not give syntax error to `&Test::...Rest`? And how is it able to build something that is actually a syntax error?